# Cloning PostgreSQL 8.3.7

Tags: postgresql, clone

I need to clone PostgreSQL 8.3.7 from one server to another with minimum downtime.

My current approach is:
1. pg_start_backup on the source database.
2. create snapshot of the file system on source database server
3. pg_stop backup on the source database.
3. copy pg_data directory from the source to the destination server
4. copy all the remaining WAL files from pg_xlog to the destination server.

I don't know how to tell PostgreSQL to apply all the WAL files.
I want to do it manually and I don't want to set up "warm standby".

Is there any command I need to execute that instructs PostgreSQL to apply WAL files and is there a way to check which WAL files got applied?

Comment: (a) It should just do it, and (b) the logs. Id try it with a small installation first so you can get a feel for it - do make sure it's an active small installation though to get changes while copying.

Comment: The problem is that there was no records in the logs indicating that WAL files got applied. I'll check maybe log level needs to be different.

Comment: Don't forget the backup-related functions too: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-BACKUP

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking for a one-time operation, not a way to continuously keep a clone database in sync with the original.

The best approach avoiding *any* downtime is to:

1. `rsync` the file system(s) containing the database directory and transaction logs (`pg_xlog`) to the clone location,
2. call `pg_start_backup()`,
3. `rsync` the file system(s) containing the database directory and transaction logs (`pg_xlog`) to the clone location **again** — this should take a much shorter period of time than the first `rsync`, and finally
4. call `pg_stop_backup()`.

Now if you start up PostgreSQL on the clone, it will **automatically** recover the cloned database and transaction log and start accepting queries.  I am not aware of a way to **manually** apply the transaction log.

Comment: >> >> Now if you start up PostgreSQL on the clone, it will automatically recover the cloned database and transaction log and start accepting queries.

And this is what happened, but because I didn't see entries in the log file (in pg_log directory), I wasn't sure if WAL files got applied and which ones got applied. Well good to know that I don't need to run anything extra, I'll do more checks / tests, maybe create a record on primary database and see if it gets applied via WAL file application. Thanks.